# PANDAS Data structure function

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am writing a function called `series_from_counts(count_dict)` that:

- Takes a dictionary in the format of the output of a previous function's return value in the form of a dictionary object as an input
- Creates and returns a Series with the name Count
- Index is the letter
- Also draws a barplot with a bar for each letter using seaborn.barplot

And uses the two lines given below:

```
sns.barplot() # fill in the parentheses
plt.show() # do not change
```

My code is :

```
def series_from_counts(count_dict):
    dictionary = count_dict
    data = dictionary
    names = list(data.keys())
    values = list(data.values())
    Count = pd.Series(data, index=keys)
    index = pd.set_index('letter')
    sns.barplot(range(len(data)),values,tick_label=names))
    plt.show() # do not change
```

What do I need to change in my code to generate the correct bar graph that takes a dictionary as input and returns a series where the letters from the dictionary are the indices and the counts (integers) are stored in the series.  Series is renamed to "Count", where the function produces a barplot showing the count for each letter and produces a vertically oriented figure with the title "Word count by letter."

Expected output looks like:

For example, if the input dictionary is:

```
{'g': 3, 'c': 1, 'f': 1}
```

The output series would be:

```
c1
f1
g3
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try and re-state your problem:

*You have a dictionary with letters as keys and integers as values.  You want to produce a bar graph where the dictionary keys are the labels and the dictionary values are the heights of the bars.*

If that's right, the following will do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'g': 3, 'c': 1, 'f': 1}
s = pd.Series(d)
sns.barplot(s.index, s.values).set_title('Word count by letter')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! The only component I'm missing is how to add a title to the bar plot produced ?